# Vertical bar next to string of text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a vertical bar next to a string of text similar to this:

```
| String of text
```

this is my current code

```
.line{
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    height:1em;
}
```

in my HTML:

```
<span class="line"></span>Past Projects<br />
```

EDIT:How would I go about doing a fadein using jQuery. I'm using this code, but it highlights all of the text even though I come only into the vicinity of one. I'm also having trouble with the fact that my text is being displaced by the vertical bar when it fades in.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('details').mouseenter(function(){
        $('line').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

where details is the text, and line is the border which I've changed to:

```
.line{
    border-style:solid;
    border-left: double-thick;
    border-color: #00ff00;
    margin-right: .5em;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: How would I go about changing the displacement that the border causes when it fades in and out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
border-left: 1px solid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using opacity instead of fadeIn:

```
.line {
    border-style:solid;
    border-left: double-thick;
    border-color: #00ff00;
    margin-right: .5em;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
}
.visible {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/4bYgR/)**

Comment: why is it that it works if I call it with id="details" but not class?

Comment: I currently have it with fadein but I tried it with yours and both of them have teh space displacement when its hovered.

Answer (score 0):

for adding a | before, you can also do this :

```
.line:before {
  content: "|";
}
```